# ipfw strange rules after reboot

Tags: freebsd, ipfw

I set this lines in my rc.conf:

> firewall_enable="YES"
> firewall_type="/etc/ipfw.rules"

cat /etc/ipfw.rules

> add 02020 deny ip from table(10) to any
> add 02030 deny ip from table(11) to any dst-port 25
>
> ...

But after reboot,
ipfw show :

```
00100 allow ip from any to any via lo0
00200 deny ip from any to 127.0.0.0/8
00300 deny ip from 127.0.0.0/8 to any
00400 deny ip from any to ::1
00500 deny ip from ::1 to any
00600 allow ipv6-icmp from :: to ff02::/16
00700 allow ipv6-icmp from fe80::/10 to fe80::/10
00800 allow ipv6-icmp from fe80::/10 to ff02::/16
00900 allow ipv6-icmp from any to any ip6 icmp6types 1
01000 allow ipv6-icmp from any to any ip6 icmp6types 2,135,136
 ... after that, my rules
```

But i have not this lines about ip6 in my ipfw.rules.

How to disable this useless rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have enabled the IPv6 Firewall without configuring it,so it is defaulting to type "unknown".

Either disable the IPv6 firewall by removing `ipv6_firewall_enable="YES"`, or configure rules for the IPv6 firewall and load them as you are with the IPv4 firewall.

**Edit:**
The above is true for previous versions of FreeBSD. As of 9.0-STABLE the IPv6 and IPv4 firewall configurations are merged. The new Answer is:

Those firewall entries are considered "mandatory" and can only be disabled by editing the configuration script or rolling your own configuration script.

Comment: ipv6_firewall_enable="NO" doesnt help. Also i cant find any ipv6_firewal in /etc/default/. I understand you idea, thanks, but for now cant implement this. Nothing interesting nether in rc.firewal  about ip6, nether in /etc/defaults

Comment: What version of FreeBSD are you running?

Comment: 9.1-PRERELEASE FreeBSD 9.1-PRERELEASE #0: Tue Aug 21 22:39:46 YEKT 2012